# How to remove cursor in Sublime Text 3 for Windows?

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

Is there a way to 'remove' one of multiple cursors after specifying it using the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and use the middle mouse button to "subtract" from a selection. Also, if you are making multiple selections and want to remove the last one, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.